# Firebase authentication phone number for android: SMS template in different languages

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using sms Firebase authentication on the android application. However, the SMS I am receiving is weird: Part of it is sometimes English and part of it is Arabic and the rest of the SMS I can't make out actually. 
[image]

How to make the SMS's language received only Arabic without the other characters?

Comment: Yes, language other than the English doesn't work that good. Seems that they are working on it.

Comment: The part with the non-Arabic language is likely the app name from the App store or Google play store.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether your phone language and Firebase console are same. Otherwise this can happen. Firebase rechecks the locale of the phone that's causing the issue.
[image]

Comment: As a matter of fact the language in the setting page is set to Arabic. But still when the SMS is received, there is non Arabic characters.

Comment: did you also set the language to Arabic in Firebase console.

Comment: Is there a page to sit the language to Arabic other than this page?